# How to Import a Python "wheel" into SnowFlake as Package

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can someone show me how to import a "wheel" file into SnowFlake?

I would like to import a Python "wheel" file that has been downloaded from PyPi, but not sure how to go about it.

I tried some guidance from the following link but no luck
https://medium.com/snowflake/running-pip-packages-in-snowflake-d43581a67439

Comment: What issues have you had so far when following that article?

Comment: Hi Sergiu,
When I attempt to execute step 2 on PC I get the error. ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'```

Comment: However, I don't get the error when I execute on a python sheet in SnowFlake

Comment: Step 2 is not going to work on your local PC, it needs to be a file uploaded in the same way as in step 3. See my reply [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D5Do00000Z867kKAB/importing-python-wheel-into-snowflake-packages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the wheel from pypi.org
2. Create the wheel_loader.py script as in the Medium article
3. Using SnowSQL, PUT the wheel and wheel loader script into the stage
4. Create the Python UDF (steps 5-7)
5. Import the wheel and script

```
imports=('@PYTHON_PACKAGES/wheel_loader.py',
         '@PYTHON_PACKAGES/TheWheelFileName.whl'
        )
```

6. In your handler function, run the wheel loader script
   `wheel_loader.load('TheWheelFileName.whl')`
7. After the wheel load, import from the wheel package
   `from TheWheelPackage import some_function, another_function`

Actually the wheel loader script does not appear to always be required. I have a working UDF that simply imports the wheel and adds it to the system path. It is unclear to me when the wheel loader approach may be required and when a simple import/add to system path may suffice.

```
create or replace function ULID()
returns string
language python
volatile
runtime_version = '3.8'
imports=('@PYTHON_PACKAGES/python_ulid-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl')
handler = 'ulid'
as
$$
import sys

import_dir = sys._xoptions.get("snowflake_import_directory")
sys.path.append(import_dir + '/python_ulid-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl')

def ulid():
  import ulid
  ulid = ulid.ULID()
  return str(ulid)
$$;
```

Comment: Actually the wheel loader script does not appear to always be required. I have a working UDF that simply imports the wheel and adds it to the system path.